# Disable Lightning sound

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I'm on a server that has custom enchantments. One of them is *Storm* which gives players a chance to strike their enemy with lightning. Players all over the world are fighting and that thunder roaring is absolutely annoying.

Is there anyway to change or disable the thunderstorm sound without turning off all weather sounds?
Thanks

Comment: Have you tried `entitydata @e[type=lightning_bolt] {Silent:1b}`? I can't test it right now, but if you place that in a repeating command block, it should mute all the lightning bolts. All of them, including those that come with a thunderstorm. I'm not sure if it works, so I won't post it as an answer.

Comment: @D-Inventor Lightning bolts cannot be targeted with selectors (and when using `/summon` to create a lightning bolt, NBT data is ignored).

Comment: @D-Inventor I'm not allowed to do that anyway. i was hoping to change it manually in the .minecraft folder

Comment: So you want a server resource packs that makes lightnings silent?

Comment: @D-Inventor if he's on a server he won't be able to use command blocks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible to make all large echo sounds from lightning in far away locations silent through use of a resource pack.

This can be achieved through the following steps:

1. Create a folder in your resource packs folder with the name of your choice
2. Inside your new folder put use a text editor to make a text file containing the text:

   ```
   {
       "pack":{
           "pack_format":3,
           "description":"Put whatever you want here"
       }
   }
   ```

   and save it as the file format: .mcmeta
3. In the first file you created make another folder inside it called `assets`
4. Inside the `assets` folder make another folder called `minecraft`
5. Inside your `minecraft` folder make another folder called `sounds`
6. Inside `sounds` make a folder called `ambient`
7. Inside `ambient` make `weather`
8. Download a .ogg sound which is silent (you can get one [here](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Silence.ogg))
9. Copy and paste 3 silent .ogg noises you downloaded into your `weather` file
10. name them `thunder1`, `thunder2` and `thunder3`

the location of the 3 thunder sounds should be `.minecraft\resourcepacks\RESOURCEPACK\assets\minecraft\sounds\ambient\weather\`

Now go onto Minecraft and use your resource pack that you made. Now you wont hear any thunder sounds.

Comment: I had a texturepack and i just put those folders in it and worked perfectly. Thanks